# Eureka only displays 1 instance of .NET service

Tags: .net, netflix-eureka

I 've built an eureka server and a .net core service. I've configed service to register with eureka, but when I start 2 .net core services, I only see 1 instance of service in eureka dashboard.
Here is my appsettings.json file config of .net core service:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "spring": {
    "application": {
      "name": "dotnetapp"
    }
  },
  "eureka": {
    "client": {
      "shouldRegisterWithEureka": true,
      "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:8761/eureka",
      "shouldFetchRegistry": "false",
      "ValidateCertificates": false
    },
    "instance": {
      "appName": "dotnet",
      "hostName": "localhost",
      "port": 57903
    }
  }
}
```

I have installed 2 services with different ports in IIS (port 57903 and 8088 in IIS). For port 8088 I've change above appsettings.json file with "port: 8088. Browse 2 links http://localhost:8088 and http://localhost:57903 are okie, but only one instance is displayed on eureka dashboard.
Can any one tell me why and how I fix this issue to adopt load balancing?